# CSVhelper any way to ignore "=" present in CSV

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have an application which generates CSV data. This application "helpfully" includes the Excel fix of using `=` as a preamble to quoted 0-filled numeric data, to prevent the Excel interpreter from eating the leading 0.

I want to use `CSVHelper` to read these records. However, when mapping to a number, `CSVhelper` reports an error for these values with the `=` prefix.

Other than search/replace to pull the "=" out, is there a way to tell CSVhelper to ignore the leading equals and process successfully?  I see options for including = in the written output but not to allow them in the parse.

Here is an example record:

```
"XYZ INC","R1G202113","R2G",="202113","D-SRS PRO FLD SM/2",157.49,122.53,True,50,50,0.00,1,False,"N",4.00,6.00,8.00,6.00,""
```

Any hep with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, and there may be a much better way, but perhaps you could do something like this with your mapping:

```
public class MyData
{
    //map the raw input to this field as a string
    public string MappedIntField {get;set;}=null;


    // use an integer property not mapped to any column to shadow the string, and lazy-convert to an integer the first time you read it.
    public int ActualIntField 
    {
        get {
            if (MappingReady || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MappedIntField)) return _ActualIntField;

            //clean up the extra = character.
            if (MappedIntField[0] == '=') MappedIntField = MappedIntField.Substring(1);

            int result; 
            if (int.TryParse(MappedIntField, out result))
            {
                 _ActualIntField = result;
                 MappingReady = true;
                 return result;
            }
            return _ActualIntField;             
        }
        set {
            _ActualIntField = value;
            MappingReady = true;
        }
    }
    private int _AcutalIntField;
    // We don't want to re-parse the string on every read, so also flag when this work is done. You could also use a nullable int? to do this.
    private bool MappingReady = false;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Joel, didn’t think of mapping that as a field.  I wonder if it not having delims is an issue, IE no extra ","

Comment: @Davery I see what you're saying. I didn't notice at first the `=` sign is not inside the quotes, but rather precedes them. I expect this basic technique would still work, but CSVHelper would also import the quotes as part of the data, and so you'll need just a little more code to also strip them off before parsing the integer.

Comment: @Davery I can find a way to *generate* CSV with prepended `=` using CSVHelper, but not a way to *read* such content.  See [CSVHelper issue 527](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/527) and [CsvHelper.Contrib issue 7](https://github.com/CsvHelperContrib/CsvHelperContrib/issues/7).  I expect something similar exists for reading, but I can't find it.

Comment: `="0123"` will import a formula in Excel (tested in Excel 2013). Importing such a values would need `csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;` (or it could be done the way shown above)